# Reading sensors into python array and parsing with PHP

Tags: python, php

everyone,
So here's what I'm doing. I'm going to have a raspberry pi with a bunch of proximity sensors attached (for the purposes of my question, let's say 20). I want to create a PHP page that when loaded will execute a python script to check the status of the sensors (true if something is near and false if not). Then the PHP page will build a table with the status results in it (red background if true, green if false).

I'm pretty sure I can work out the code for reading the sensors in the script and the code for building the table in PHP. The questions that I have are how would I pass the array back and would I have to use a for loop to parse the results and create my table?

I have a feeling I'll be back with more questions, but for now, these are the pressing ones.
Thanks.
Patrick.

Comment: If you make the Python script return a JSON object you can let PHP decode it to an array, then loop through it. Another approach could be to use Python to fill the database and only use PHP to read from it

Comment: If I create a JSON object using Python, would I be able to use that with Sharepoint (ASP, I'm assuming) also? And would PHP/ASP be able to call the Python script on the fly as needed?

Comment: "would I be able to use that with Sharepoint" What do you mean by using it with Sharepoint? You could call the Python script by PHP. But if you let the python script execute periodically by a cronjob and fill the database, you only need to use PHP to read the values from the database if you want to.

Comment: I'll clarify a little. This is a project that a coworker is doing. He wants to set up an alert system for when parts bins need to be filled. They'll put the bins on a slat-wall, and the proximity sensors will register that the bin is there. He wants to have it sent to his SharePoint site, if possible instead of having to refresh a page on a server located on the Pi.

I guess what I'm looking for is either the page auto-refreshes or they refresh it and it sends the request for the updated values of the sensors.

Comment: I would advice to use a cronjob to perodically check the sensors and fill the database with the Python script. That way the values are always updated and the PHP page always has the latest status available in the database without having to wait for the Python script to finish executing. If you schedule the cronjob every minute you always have the latest status of max 59 seconds ago.

Comment: Check this diagram https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tH-Gd85qigtA5NhhkHzyPLKXHQdQjITf/view?usp=sharing